# Implementing assembly logical 'not' instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

So I have run into a problem in assembly language. I need a way to get the same desired result from the 'not' instruction by only using the 'and' and 'or' instructions. So if I have:

```
AL = 1011000

not AL = 0100111
```

but I need that result using only and/or instructions.

I assume I have to use masking bits and such, but have had no luck thus far. Even a little nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible with only AND and OR.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty easy:

```
mov ah, 11111111b    ; this is your mask
mov al, 00010011b    ; anything you want the 'not' from
xor al, ah
```

That's it! Didn't even used the and operator.
I don't know what assembler you're using but this worked with nasm.

Comment: OP clearly said, "only using AND and OR" operations.  XOR is not one of these.

Comment: @IraBaxter I know, but it's impossible with only AND and OR. XOR is at least similar to OR ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a loop (untested). But its a waste of registers.

```
NotAL:
    mov bl, 1
    mov bh, 0feh
L3:
    test al, bl
    jne L1
    or al, bl
    jmp L2
L1:
    and al, bh
L2:
    shl bl, 1
    rol bh, 1
    test bl, bl
    jne L3

    ret
```

Comment: If you are willing to use instructions other than "AND" and "OR" as OP specified, you could just use  "mov AH,0", "sub AH, AL", "DEC AH".

Comment: Yes thats correct. This is a very simple solution using the 2 complement. Very clever!